# Flot will not Zoom if xaxis is in the time mode

Tags: time, flot, mode

I am using [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) zooming via jquery.flot.navigate.js
Zooming via the mousewheel on stops working if I am using xaxis in mode: "time". Zooming by double clicking continues to work.

### See example:

```
var plot;
$(function () {
    var d3 = [[1350645091000, 1.54], [1351287868000, 1.59], [1351546638000, 1.59]];
    var d2 = [[1350645091000, 3.4], [1351287868000, 3.51], [1351546638000, 3.51]];
    var d1 = [[1350645091000, 1], [1351287868000, 1], [1351546638000, 1]];
    var all_data = [{ 
        label: 'PageRank = 1.00', color: '#119F11', data: d1
    }, { 
        label: 'Real PageRank = 3.51', color: '#14C914', data: d2
    }, { 
        label: 'TrustRank(sm) = 1.59', color: '#0D8FDD', data: d3
    }];

    var plot_conf = {
        series: {
            points: { 
                show: true 
            },
            lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 1.5
            },
            shadowSize: 1.5
        },
        crosshair: { 
            mode: 'x' 
        },
        grid: { 
            hoverable: true, 
            autoHighlight: false 
        },
        legend: {
            noColumns: 3,
            container: $('#legend')
        },
        zoom: {
            interactive: true
           },
        pan: {
            interactive: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: 'time',
            timeformat: '%d.%m.%Y ',
            timezone: 'browser',
            zoomRange: [0.1, 10], 
            panRange: [1350218985000, 1351738106000]
        },
        yaxis: {
            zoomRange: [0.1, 10], 
            panRange: [-1, 11]
        }
    };

    plot = $.plot($('#placeholder'), all_data, plot_conf);

    $('#placeholder').bind('plotzoom', function (event, plot) {
        legends();
    });

    $('#placeholder').bind('plotpan', function (event, plot) {
        legends();
    });

    legends();

    // Cross --------------------------
    function legends() {
        var legends = $('#legend .legendLabel');
        legends.each(function () {
            // fix the widths so they don't jump around
            $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
        });

        var updateLegendTimeout = null;
        var latestPosition = null;

        function updateLegend() {
            updateLegendTimeout = null;
            var pos = latestPosition;
            var axes = plot.getAxes();
            if (pos.x < axes.xaxis.min || pos.x > axes.xaxis.max ||
                pos.y < axes.yaxis.min || pos.y > axes.yaxis.max) {
                return;
            }

            var i, j, dataset = plot.getData();
            for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; ++i) {
                var series = dataset[i];
                // find the nearest points, x-wise
                for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; ++j) {
                    if (series.data[j][0] > pos.x) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // now interpolate
                var y, p1 = series.data[j - 1], p2 = series.data[j];
                if (p1 == null) {
                    y = p2[1];
                }
                else if (p2 == null) {
                    y = p1[1];
                }
                else {
                    y = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * (pos.x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);
                }
                legends.eq(i).text(series.label.replace(/=.*/, '= ' + y.toFixed(2)));
            }
        }

        $('#placeholder').bind('plothover', function (event, pos, item) {
            latestPosition = pos;
            if (!updateLegendTimeout) {
               updateLegendTimeout = setTimeout(updateLegend, 50);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

So, can anybody give me a hint to force zoom working with xaxis switched to mode: "time"?

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems - one, zooming with the mousewheel does not work.  Two, zooming on the xaxis does not work.

**For problem #1:**

Double click zoom works, but mouse wheel zoom does not.  This is with jQuery 1.7.2 or greater.  If I change to jQuery 1.6.4, it starts working again.

The reason is that the [navigate plugin](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js) from flot 0.7 includes a mousewheel plugin that is not compatible with newer jQuery versions.  I can't exactly tell why due to it being compressed inline into the navigate plugin.

You can see the error if you add something like this to the code:

```
placeholder.bind('plotzoom', function (event, plot) {
    var axes = plot.getAxes();
    $(".message").html("Zooming to x: "  + axes.xaxis.min.toFixed(2)
                       + " &ndash; " + axes.xaxis.max.toFixed(2)
                       + " and y: " + axes.yaxis.min.toFixed(2)
                       + " &ndash; " + axes.yaxis.max.toFixed(2));
});
```

It will always show `NaN` for all 4 values, when they should be numbers.  This is because the mousewheel events don't have proper pageX/pageY parameters.

Your alternatives are to use an older jQuery, or use a newer version of the navigate plugin from [github](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.navigate.js).

**For problem #2:**

In order to get xaxis zooming to work, you need to use a `zoomRange` that counts in milliseconds (?).  I played around with it a bit and found that changing your `xaxis` zoomRange from `[0.1,10]` to `[0.1,3600000000]` made the zooming work.

Here it is working with the newer navigate plugin (but older flot) and changed `zoomRange`:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Men3X/2/

Comment: I added message: mouse wheel zooming does not work, not double clicking.

Comment: @IgorIvanov your example doesn't seem like the mouse wheel zooming in non `time` mode either?  But I see the problem now...

Comment: I am using the latest version of flot plugin (and it's using jQuery v1.5.1). I tried it with jQuery v1.6.4, the same result.  As you can see in your example, we have only yaxis zooming, but we need also xaxis zooming, which placed in mode "time".  So, we have that it does not work properly with jQuery v1.5.1  and v1.6.4,  and does not work at all with latest versions (1.7.2 and 1.8.2) of jQuery. I think that it's fault of flot plugin. Does anyone know how to contact the developer of this plugin? I did not find it by myself.  
Can anybody help with it?